# do I have to re-type class for each element I want to alter under that class?

Tags: html, css

This is a simple question but I didn't know how to word it, but would I have to re-type the class for each element I want to alter under that class?

For example:

Can I just do

```
.update-content>h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {}
```

or do I have to do like this?

```
.update-content>h1,
.update-content>h2,
.update-content>h3,
.update-content>h4,
.update-content>h5,
.update-content>h6 {}
```

I understand if the first one is wrong because the class is only pointing at the h1 element. Thanks!

Also if anyone can answer this, I'd be glad. In HTML and CSS there are IDs and classes. What could you call them as a collective (ids, classes), identifiers?

Comment: you can use like this .update-content>h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 { ... }

Comment: @IqbalPasha No...you can't. - Here's why not. - https://jsfiddle.net/kpx34n1d/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, unfortunately, you do have to call them individually.

There is no method of 'grouping' elements to apply specific styles as you wish to do...that is there is no "all headings" selector.

There are preprocessors that make *writing* the CSS quicker but in the end, the output is *still* exactly what you indicated:

For instance..in [**SCSS**](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/9be65b3cf284517e04d6) you can write:

```
.update-content > {

    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
      color:red
    }
}
```

and get:

```
.update-content>h1,
.update-content>h2,
.update-content>h3,
.update-content>h4,
.update-content>h5,
.update-content>h6 {color:red}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Whether it possible?**

Unfortunatelly you cannot alter  them by `.update-content>h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6`, see **@Paulie_D** answer for more info regarding selecting elements.

**Do class and id collective identifiers?**

**Class** is collective identifier.Source: [w3c.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-class)

> class = cdata-list [CS]   This attribute assigns a class name or set
>   of class names to an element. Any number of elements may be assigned
>   the same class name or names. Multiple class names must be separated
>   by white space characters.

**Id** is for unique elements.Source: [w3c.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id)

> id = name [CS]   This attribute assigns a name to an element. This
>   name must be unique in a document.

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko with your Code it will select the direct children `h1` from `update-content` and then every `h2` to `h6`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.update-content>h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 { color: blue }`

Comment: If he isn't applying global styles, why is this wrong? If he does want to use global styles, then yes it won't work. But he asked the question if his simple query would work, and it does.

Comment: It's implicit in the question what he's trying to do.